# send arguments for function arguments in python

Tags: python, arguments, function-pointers

I have a function which receives one function argument and that function argument also receives one argument but I don't know how to pass this argument to argument function in python. Here is the sample code:

```
def pr(text):
   print(text)

def frun(func):
   func()

frun(pr)
```

The question is how can I pass `text` argument in `frun(pr)`?
And please consider about using keyword arguments too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** [Partial Application](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

The problem boils down to passing `func`'s argument to the scope you want to do the evaluation in.  There are a few ways of doing this.

**Explicit Parameterization**

This get's unwieldy if you have numerous functions, or deep function call trees.

```
def pr(text):
  print(text)

def frun(func, *func_args):
  func(*func_args)

frun(pr, *pr_args)
```

**[Deferred Execution with Lambda](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda)**

Limitation: You need all the arguments for `func` available at the same time, when you create the `lambda`.

```
def pr(text):
  print(text)

def frun(func):
  func()

frun(lambda: pr(*pr_args))
```

**[Partial Application](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)**

Here the nice thing is you can do partial application as the object get's passed along.  If you `partial` using named variables then you eliminate the ordering issue of the arguments.

```
from functools import partial

def pr(text):
  print(text)

def frun(func):
  func()

frun(partial(pr, *pr_args))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one argument, you can do:

```
def pr(text):
   print(text)

def frun(func, text):
   func(text)

frun(pr, "blah")
```

Otherwise, you can use variable arguments "magic" like:

```
def pr(text):
   print(text)

def frun(func, *args):
   func(*args)

frun(pr, "blah")
```

The latter is far less readable and could lead to weird errors (in this case, it won't even work with more than one parameter passed, because `pr` expects only one positional argument), still is sometimes necessary. For instance, when you don't know *a priori* how many parameters your function will need:

```
def pr1(text):
    print(text)

def pr2(text, note):
    print(text, note)

def frun(func, *args):
   func(*args)

frun(pr1, "foobarbaz")
frun(pr2, "blah", "IT WORKS!")
```

Comment: Thanks, but your answer isn't good on key argument and some how doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `lambda` function to pass `pr` function along with parameters to `frun` function, without changing your code.

```
def pr(text):
    print(text)

# just another example to show how to pass more than one argument.
def pr2(text, note):
    print(text, note)


def frun(func):
    func()


frun(lambda: pr('Hello'))
frun(lambda: pr2('Hello', 'World'))

Hello
Hello World
```

Another way that may be useful for you is to return `func` in `frun` as `callback` function,
 and then call it with parameters:

```
def pr(text):
    print(text)

# just another example to show how to pass more than one argument.
def pr2(text, note):
    print(text, note)


def frun(func):
    # do some stuff
    return func


frun(pr)('Hello')
frun(pr2)('Hello', 'World')


Hello
Hello World
```